# Обновление datatable используя SqlDependency

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Как можно обновить DataTable с помощью `SqlDependency`?

```
public void StartWatching() {
  SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
  SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
  ExecuteWatchingQuery();
}
static void Main(string[] args) {}
private void ExecuteWatchingQuery() {
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    connection.Open();
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(
      "select * from Shedule", connection)) {
      var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
      bool res = SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

      sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseChange);

      command.ExecuteReader();
    }
  }
  Console.Read();
}
private void OnDatabaseChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args) {
  SqlNotificationInfo info = args.Info;
  if (SqlNotificationInfo.Insert.Equals(info) || SqlNotificationInfo.Update.Equals(info) || SqlNotificationInfo.Delete.Equals(info))

    Console.WriteLine("Change...");


  ExecuteWatchingQuery();


}
```

Вот так примерно. Программа написана на Console app

Comment: В событии `OnDatabaseChange` открываете соединение к базе, и считывааете новые данные в `DataTable`.

Comment: `static void Main(string[] args) {}` что делает этот метод? Методы класса самого консольного приложения, если вы планируете вызывать их в `Main` должны быть статическими. Это только беглый взгляд. Или в приведенном коде солянка из методов разных классов?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите.

Обычные CRUD-операции не дают вам возможности узнать, обновилась ли база данных из какого-нибудь другого приложения, разве что время от времени перечитывать.

`SqlDependency` позволяет вам узнать, когда же определённая часть базы поменяется, но не предоставляет вам новые данные. Поэтому вы должны делать так:

1. Создать `SqlDependency` и подписаться на `OnChange`.
2. Загрузить данные обычным образом, без `SqlDependency`.
3. По приходу `OnChange` вы знаете, что данные изменились, так что нужно перечитать данные *точно так же* как в пункте 2.